# Django-widget-tweaks ошибки при валидации формы

Tags: django

Использую Django-widget-tweaks для рендера формы в html. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой. Форма отображается корректно, но при отправке на сервер, если форма не прошла проверку, не отображаются допущенные ошибки. Если не пользоваться Django-widget-tweaks то все в порядке, ошибки появляются.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import register


def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = register(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Аккаунт {username} был создан, введите имя пользователя и пароль для авторизации')
            return redirect('main')
    else:
        form = register()
    return render(request, 'users/registration.html', {'form': form, 'title':'Регистрация пользователя'})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class register(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password1', 'password2', 'email']
```

html шаблон

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block main_section %}
  <div class="title">Авторизация</div>
    <form method="POST" class="main-form">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="id_username" class="form-label">Введите логин</label>
        {% render_field form.username class="form-input" placeholder="Введите имя"%}
      </div>
      <div class="form-item">
        <label for="id_password" class="form-label">Введите пароль</label>
        {% render_field form.password class="form-input" placeholder="Введите пароль"%}
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Войти</button>
        <p>Забыли пароль? <a href="{% url 'auth' %}">Восстановить</a></p>
      </div>      
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы должны выводить ошибки вручную.

Данный код выведет все ошибки в одном месте:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% block main_section %}
<div class="title">Авторизация</div>
    <form method="POST" class="main-form">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="id_username" class="form-label">Введите логин</label>
            {% render_field form.username class="form-input" placeholder="Введите имя"%}
        </div>
        <div class="form-item">
            <label for="id_password" class="form-label">Введите пароль</label>
            {% render_field form.password class="form-input" placeholder="Введите пароль"%}
        </div>

        {% for error in form.errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}

        <div class="center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Войти</button>
            <p>Забыли пароль? <a href="{% url 'auth' %}">Восстановить</a></p>
        </div>      
   </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Если хотите, что бы ошибки выводились над каждым полем, то ошибки обрабатывать так:

```
<div class="form-item">
    {% if form.username.errors %} {{ form.username.errors }} {% endif %}
    <label for="id_username" class="form-label">Введите логин</label>
    {% render_field form.username class="form-input" placeholder="Введите имя"%}
</div>
```